# Running Multiple Linear Regression Models in for-Loop

Tags: r, for-loop

The logic is similar to the content-based recommender,

| content | undesirable | desirable | user_1 | ... | user_10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.00 | 2.77 | 0.11 |  | NA |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5000 | 2.50 | 2.11 | NA |  | 0.12 |

I need to run the model for undesirable and desirable as independent values and each user as the dependent value, thus I need run 10 times to fit the model and predict each user's NA value.

This is the code that I hard coding, but I wonder how to use for loop, I just searched for several methods but they do not work for me...

the data as 'test'

```
hard code

#fit model
fit_1 = lm(user_1 ~ undesirable + desirable, data = test)
...
fit_10 = lm(user_10 ~ undesirable + desirable, data = test)

#prediction
u_1_na = test[is.na(test$user_1), c('user_1', 'undesirable', 'desirable')]
result1 = predict(fit_1, newdata = u_1_na)
which(result1 == max(result1))
max(result1)
...
u_10_na = test[is.na(test$user_10), c('user_10', 'undesirable', 'desirable')]
result10 = predict(fit_10, newdata = u_10_na)
which(result10 == max(result10))
max(result10)

#make to csv file
apply each max predict value to csv.
```

this is what I try for now(for loop)

```
mod_summaries <- list() 

for(i in 1:10) {                 
  
  predictors_i <- colnames(data)[1:10]   
  mod_summaries[[i - 1]] <- summary(     
    lm(predictors_i ~ ., test[ , c("undesirable", 'desirable')]))
  
}
```

Comment: Create the formulas as string `formulas <- paste0("user_", 1:10, " ~ undesirable + desirable"` use them to iterate and create the regressions `models <- lapply(formulas, \(x)lm(as.formula(x), data = test))`

Comment: R is an index 1 language, no need to subtract 1 from i, `i - 1`, as index 0 languages like Python require. Simply refer to `i`.

Comment: @M.Viking “Like index 0 like Python require” — err this isn’t really required in Python either since virtually every iteration starts at 0, not at 1.

Comment: @Oliver, Yeah, this is work for me, but I still need to use the model to predict the NA for each user..

Answer (score 1):

An apply method:

```
mod_summaries_lapply <-
  lapply(
    colnames(mtcars),
    FUN = function(x)
      summary(lm(reformulate(".", response = x), data = mtcars))
  )
```

A for loop method to make linear models for each column. The key is the `reformulate()` function, which creates the formula from strings. In the question, the function is made of a string and results in  error `invalid term in model formula`. The string needs to be evaluated with `eval()` . This example uses the mtcars dataset.

```
mod_summaries <- list() 
for(i in 1:11) {                 
  predictors_i <- colnames(mtcars)[i]   
  mod_summaries[[i]] <- summary(lm(reformulate(".", response = predictors_i), data=mtcars))
  #summary(lm(reformulate(". -1", response = predictors_i), data=mtcars))  # -1 to exclude intercept
  #summary(lm(as.formula(paste(predictors_i, "~ .")), data=mtcars)) # a "paste as formula" method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function `as.formula` together with the `paste` function to create your formula. Following is an example

```
formula_lm <- as.formula(
    paste(response_var, 
          paste(expl_var, collapse = " + "), 
          sep = " ~ "))
```

This implies that you have more than one explanatory variable (separated in the `paste` with +). If you only have one, omit the second `paste`.

With the created formula, you can use the `lm` funciton like this:

```
lm(formula_lm, data)
```

Edit: the vector `expl_var` would in your case include the undesirable and desirable variable.

Comment: While this is possible and fairly common, it's actually quite convoluted. R has a conceptually simpler and much more elegant way of dynamically creating formulas, namely by interpolating a variable into an unevaluated expression, e.g.: `eval(bquote(.(response_var) ~ .))`.

Comment: Thanks Konrad, learned something new! Did not know that the function `bquote` existed. Altough I think that the readability suffers a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the loop.  Make your data [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).  Something like:

```
library(tidyverse)

test %>%
  select(-content) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    starts_with("user"),
    names_to="user",
    values_to="value"
  ) %>%
  group_by(user) %>%
  group_map(
    function(.x, .y) {
      summary(lm(user ~ ., data=.x))
    }
  )
```

Untested code since your example is not [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).