# r programming, for loop to run prediction model

Tags: r, for-loop

There are 10 models to estimate each user,
So I need to run 10 times to predict for each user and want to make a data frame as max value for each prediction

```
test = data
```

run the model predict and save as result1, repeat 10 times

```
result1 = data.frame(predict(models[[1]], newdata = test[is.na(test$u_1), c('u_1', 'undesirable', 'desirable')]))
....
result10 = data.frame(predict(models[[10]], newdata = test[is.na(test$u_10), c('u_10', 'undesirable', 'desirable')]))
```

take the max value for each prediction and repeat 10 times,

```
tec_1 = which(result1 == max(result1), arr.ind=TRUE)
....
tec_10 = which(result10 == max(result10), arr.ind=TRUE)
```

and make it to data frame

```
a = rbind(tec_1,tec_2,tec_3,tec_4,tec_5,tec_6,tec_7,tec_8,tec_9,tec_10)
final_df = cbind(products = rownames(a), a)
final_df = data.frame(final_df[, 1])
colnames(final_df) <- c('products')
```

the code I shown is I write as a hard coding, but I want to do as for-loop,
final_df

Comment: Consider using a `list`.

Comment: This looks remarkably similar to the [question you posted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74434075/running-multiple-linear-regression-models-in-for-loop).  Please explain what is sufficiently different to warrant a new question rather than an update to the original.